# powerd.service takes eternity to start at boot

Tags: boot, systemd

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
    1min 30.182s powerd.service
          7.348s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          7.270s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          3.419s systemd-udev-settle.service
          1.639s apache2.service
          1.610s schroot.service
          1.029s mysql.service
```

(I dropped all things <1 sec)

What powerd.service is supposed to do? How can I speed it up?

I'm on a 64bit desktop, on vivid

Comment: i was searching for a solution to this issue on my laptop caused but **unity 8** although i remove **unity 8**  so i simply disable this service using this command `systemctl disable powerd.service`

Answer (score 2):

I know Vivid isn't already supported, but I think problem is in all releases. Anyway, for future reference: `powerd` it's a [service for phablet](https://launchpad.net/powerd), so it's not available in standard installation.

I opened a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/powerd/+bug/1443278) to report the strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

powerd is a daemon used to monitor a connected UPS, if one isn't connected this daemon will fail to start.

http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=ManPage&sec=8&manpage=powerd

it can be safely disabled and the package removed from the system with:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable powerd.service
```

or

```
$ sudo apt remove powerd
```